# Google OAuth2 and iOS cross site

Tags: google-oauth

I have attempted to use SDK to do cross site authentications: get code and then on the server side obtain a token for that code, but I am not sure that is implemented/working yet using Google+ sign in. Can anyone confirm that this is the case?
Since I could not get that to work I attempted to do the same using Web server applications method. But still have some problems questions that need clarification.
I have 2 entries for client ids: 
Client ID for web application
Client ID for iOS application
I assumed that I would request a code on iOS, usine Client ID for iOS and than pass it to the server which in turn will request token. But I think that would not work because code is issued for a different client.
Do I request code and then token for web application on iOS and then pass that token to my server?
What is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I was able to get this to work as of today is through the use of webview, using web application id and redirect mechanism to authenticate my server. And handle authentication on the server sending response back to the client app on ios again through web view response mechanism. Will have to live with this for now, more work but not sure there is anyway around it at this time.

This is now supported by Google Plus Button functionality. Instructions are at [Google+ Platform for iOS](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/sign-in)